# Where do I put business rules for Code First entities

Tags: entity-framework

We're using MVP and Entity Framework code first for our project. For most basic functions we'll use the DbContext, but we would like to wrap some logic around adding Profiles. Validations and some other rules.

So our object is defined as usual:

```
public class Profile:BaseEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]     
    public Guid ProfileId {get; set; }
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    //....
}
```

I'd love to have a method I can call like this:

```
var newProfile = new Profile
{
    FirstName = "John", 
    ...
}
newProfile.Insert();
// or 
_dbContext.Profile.Add(newProfile);
```

And have that call our method to do our business rules:

```
public bool AddProfile(Profile thisProfile)
{
    // Do our business
    return true; // or false if failed
}
```

I'm just not sure where the best place to put that method is. Can I add it to Profile.cs? Should I add it into the DbContext class?

I'm not sure the best way, or best terms to search for.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the ValidateEntity method of dbcontext if you just need this for a few cases

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/validate-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx

this would only be validated when you call SaveChanges();